# C# How to manipulate key value of dictionary dynamically

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary

I have to store data in dictionary where key value will be excel spreadsheet row number. I am working with 3rd party spreadsheet control where I am storing **TunerDto** data with all spreadsheet cell tag of first column but I found 3rd party has some bug. so delete any row from spreadsheet then other row's cell tag becomes null which causing issue for me.

so for work around purpose I think I need remove dependency from cell tag of spreadsheet control and maintain this info in dictionary where dictionary key value will be spreadsheet row number because spreadsheet row number is unique.

I am storing data in dictionary where key value is excel spreadsheet row number and value field is my class instance of **TunerDto** class.

this way I am storing data into dictionary now.

```
TunerDto _rowref = new TunerDto();
CellRange usedRange = worksheet.Range[cutrows];
for (int i = 0; i < usedRange.RowCount; i++)
{
    Cell currentCell = usedRange[i, 0];
    if (currentCell.Tag != null)
    {
        _rowref = currentCell.Tag as TunerDto;
        dictRowReference.Add(usedRange[i, 0].RowIndex.ToString(), _rowref);
    }
}
```

The problem is suppose my spreadsheet has 10 rows with data and suddenly user cut 2nd & 3rd row and paste those rows after 5th rows. this change need to adjust or impact row number in dictionary too. so how could I do this?

Should I use dictionary for this purpose or should I use any other collection ?
dictionary lookup is very first.

If user cut 2nd & 3rd row and paste after 5th rows then how could I change row number of dictionary which is the key value in dictionary ?

please guide me how to handle this scenario with dictionary or any better data structure / collection for this purpose?

looking for suggestion and concept. Thanks

Comment: a dictionary makes no guarantee about the order of its elements. Furthermore it does not allow for duplictaes, which may occur depending on your datastructure. Seems like a simple `List<Row>` may suffice. If you really need a dictionary, you may use its sorted counterpart `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my main concern is that If user cut 2nd & 3rd row and paste after 5th rows then how could I change row number of any collection where i will store row number as key in collection ? i am not able to develop a small program which get me the desired result. any sample code & elaborate guide line would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Do you need to know the history of the row index? So if a value was stored in row 2 and then was cut and pasted to row 5 does that historical movement matter? If not, can't you just get the row index at the time of use?